# bash / gdb autocompletes core file on RedHat but not on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, gdb

When a program dumps core, we have set our `kernel.core_pattern` to put the core file in a particular location with a certain filename etc.

```
kernel.core_pattern = | /var/core_file_handler.py %e %s %p %lu %g %t
```

Here is the destination directory, and a sample core file:

```
$ ls -l /var/cores
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar 23 09:42 app

$ ls -l /var/cores/app/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 60510208 Mar 23 09:42 2016.03.23_09.42.14.867727_11_SIGSEGV_u
```

**CentOS 6.7**

On CentOS 6.7 I have bash 4.1.2 and gdb 7.5

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.5.0.20120926-26.el6)
```

When I want to open a core file, I can type gdb and then *tab complete* the path and the core file

```
gdb ./app /var/cores/app/201.... <tab>
```

This will successfully tab complete the core file name.

**Ubuntu 14.04**

On Ubuntu 14.04 I have bash 4.3.11 and gdb 7.7.1

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
```

When I want to open a core file, I can type gdb and then *tab complete* the path, but **not the core file**

```
gdb ./app /var/cores/app/  <tab> <tab> <tab>....
```

This will **not tab complete the core file name**. It just gets stuck at `/var/cores/app/` and won't go any further

- Access permissions on `/var/cores/app` is the same on both machines
- Access permissions on `/var/cores/app/core_file` is the same on both machines

**Question:**

Why can I *tab-complete* the core-file-name on CentOS but not on Ubuntu?

Comment: The bash-completion package tries to help by limiting the second arg to gdb to be a pid or a pathname that contains a filename `core` optionally followed by a `.` and digits. To override this, try copying `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gdb` into one of your bash init files, changing the last line from `complete -F _gdb gdb` to `complete -o default -F _gdb gdb` I'll post an answer after I've researched this some more.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that worked - thank you! Seems the reason it works in CentOS is that there is no completion for gdb, but there is on Ubuntu, and it's exactly as you say - requires `/path/core[.pid]` and anything else doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with programmable completion. The idea is that by excluding things which a program can't deal with, you're making live easier for users.

In practice, however, I often find that by excluding things from completion, you'll inevitably have something which completion excludes but which you really do want to use. At that point, programmable completion is a burden rather than a help.

There are three ways you can fix this issue:

- uninstall programmable completion. It's an optional feature which you don't *have* to use if you don't want to. You can do this by way of `apt-get remove bash-completion`
- if you don't want (or can't) remove bash-completion for whatever reason, you can run `complete -r`, which removes all the completion rules again. If you do this from something like `.bashrc`, the effect will be the same as the first option, except that there's a little performance loss at bash startup since the rules are processed and then removed again.
- if you just want to occasionally force bash to complete a file name, you can use `alt`+`/` rather than `tab` to force bash to perform filename completion.

Comment: Uninstalling the entirety of bash-completion and/or removing all the completion rules is probably a bit extreme. It is possible to remove just the rules for gdb. As mentioned in a comment on the question, the rules (on Ubuntu) are defined in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gdb`, so one could also alter that file to change the completion rules

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because the customized autocomplete behavior for `gdb` on your Ubuntu system doesn't match your core file name.

You can modify the behavior by adjusting the custom completion function for `gdb` at:

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gdb
```

For example, I simply have my corefiles named slightly more uniquely (`corexyx...`, so that I can avoid backing them up) which broke the completion. I changed the line:

```
COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -f -X '!?(*/)core?(.+([0-9]))' -o plusdirs \
```

to

```
COMPREPLY+=( $( compgen -f -X '!?(*/)core?(*)' -o plusdirs \
```

which just widens the pattern it accepts for core files (in particular, it doesn't need the character following `core` (if any) to be a `.`.

If to include the default matches when the "smart" completion for GDB doesn't generate any matches, you can do as Mark suggested in the comments and simply change the last line from:

```
complete -F _gdb gdb
```

to

```
complete -o default -F _gdb gdb
```

Here's the documenation for the `-o default` option:

> If the -o default option was supplied to complete when the compspec
>   was defined, readline's  default  comple‐
>          tion will be performed if the compspec (and, if attempted, the default bash completions) generate no matches.

Finally, you could disable the smart completion for GDB entirely just by commenting out the `complete -F _gdb gdb` line entirely.